# Trying to install prehung exterior door, have unual problem and not sure what to do

Tags: doors

I'm trying to fit a standard 36" x 80" prehung door with frame.

I guess over time, they’ve added concrete over concrete to the front area were the front of the condos all face each other. After taking out the door which was old and wasn’t level, I now can’t fit the new door in.

The threshold, which is the same height as the hallway, seems to be an inch lower than the concrete in front of it. When I try to put the door in there which I could jam it in there, it’s literally pressed up against the header because the bottom metal plate of the door is stuck on the higher concrete.

I guess my question is can I cut into the header? Or do I have to grind the concrete in front down?

If I grind the concrete in the front down, it’ll end up being higher than the front plate at the bottom of the door when I install and I am worried it will collect water.

Comment: This seems like a job the condo maintenance should be talked to.  If a wooden door, usually easy to trim the bottom/top a bit for fit.  Did you measure the old door?

Comment: Old door seemed like it was jammed in there barely. Was off level to begin with. It too was close to the header. 

New door is steel , measured front inside before i tore it out, would fit just fine , when I pulled it they put a wood board under the sill to make up the height for the concrete. I thought I was part of the door that’s why I thought it would fit.

Comment: I would like to think the condo fees would help a person like this.  If any work needs done in the hallway(even just the edge), condo might need to know anyway.

Comment: Cutting into the header is going to be a no-go idea. They're designed to support the load above them, and cutting them creates a dangerous situation that could, potentially, lead to building collapse. Cutting the concrete would be a much better option, though it will make one _heck_ of a mess. I'd agree that contacting the condo management would be the way to go. Of course, you're left without a front door until they get moving...